# Batch Regex: match exact window title

Tags: regex, batch-file

How can I make batch regex expression (in FINDSTR /r /c:"ng") match this window title only? It matches also MongoDB terminal window. 
"ng\>" didn't work.

[image]

Full code for context:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh ^| FINDSTR /r /c:"ng"
') do taskkill /PID %%a
```

EDIT:
Additional info from my comment under Squashman's response:
How to avoid returning multiple PIDs from last call? [script examples screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS70V.jpg)
List of opened windows: [windows screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekJL2.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the option to find at the beginning of the word worked in my testing.

```
TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh | FINDSTR "\<ng"
```

This also worked in my testing.

```
TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo:csv /nh | FINDSTR "\"ng\""
```

Comment: How to avoid last lines of this? https://imgur.com/97LfX1g List of opened windows:
https://imgur.com/OwGDoXO

Comment: Got it. Second one helped.